# Solr case insensitive indexing and search?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

Currently I am using solr5.4.1 .while Indexing is working fine, searching the data based on case -insensitive is not working.

Say I have created Projects with codes ["AnandProjectp1","AnandProjectp2","AnandProjectp3"] and names
["Project1","Project2","Project3"]

but when I am searching for code starting with 
q=project_code:a* or project_name:p* i am getting 0 results.

My Schema.xml is`

```
<field name="company_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="company_public_id" type="string" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="company_name" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="company_description" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_company_id" type="string" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_first_name" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_last_name" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_email_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" ignoreCase="true"/>
<field name="user_code" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="user_public_id" type="String" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_company_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_code" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_name" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_description" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_public_id" type="string" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="template_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="template_company_id" type="tint" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="template_public_id" type="string" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="template_description" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="template_name" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>




<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>                                       
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>                          
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>   
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

`

the schema was taken from the example schema.xml given in the examples

Comment: you are looking for the wild card search...and that can be achieved by chnaging the analzer or the filters

Answer (score 0):

ou can try by following fieldType

```
<fieldType name="wildCardType" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and also chnage the

```
<field name="project_code" type="wildCardType" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
<field name="project_name" type="wildCardType" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
```

Comment: did you restart the server ...and you need to re-index the data...after you modify the schema.xml

Comment: Did you check the same in the analysis page of solr...?

Comment: you mean the query page that we get after selecting the core

Comment: yes..there is analysis page also at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen

Comment: yes, it is also changing its values based upon the cases of the words

Comment: so do you see the token created in indexing and in search/query...are they matching..?

Comment: the raw bytes generated match when they are of the same case don't find any tokens here

Comment: can you paste the screenshot of the analysis page